# When did the Tigress action figure change hands?

Tags: kung-fu-panda

In **Kung Fu Panda 3**, we see the Tigress action figure in a panda girl's hands near the end of the movie but,  in 'Kung Fu Panda - **Secret of the Scrolls**', I see it back in a rabbit child's hands after Po's dad gives it away?

When/How did the Tigress action figure change hands?

Comment: There's a good chance I'm missing the point completely, but I'm assuming there are *many* Tigress action figures in that universe, just like they're mass-produced in ours. She's a celebrity, after all.

Comment: I'd agree with Walt. Not to mention I'm pretty sure Po said he hand made all those models. It wouldn't be too far a stretch of the imagination that he created another model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Refering to **[this](http://kungfupanda.wikia.com/wiki/Kung_Fu_Panda:_Art_of_Balance)***

> Po has two sets of these action figures: one for display, and one to play with.

***Display of action figures in the three movies***

The action figures were first created by Po, which he had started on when he was a young cub by carving bamboo into shapes of the Furious Five. However, it is known that the figures are also a commercial product.

During the end credits of **Kung fu Panda 1**, Po was seen creating an action figure of himself, as he now fought alongside the Furious Five.

The action figures appeared near the beginning of "Special Delivery", when Po accidentally knocked them over while cleaning his bedroom. Then he carefully placed the figures back on his windowsill.

In this movie in a scene, Po saw an action figure in Former Mount Penglai's young son; an action figure in Po's likeness. Po ultimately decided to let the Official's son keep the action figure, much to the child's joy.

> It is revealed that the action figures are popular in the Valley of Peace. Additionally, figures of Po and Shifu are added to the collection.

The action figures reappeared in **Kung fu Panda 2** when Mr. Ping packed Po a backpack full of items, which he thought Po would need for his journey to Gongmen City; this included the action figures.

Later on, the figures played a large part in infiltrating the Tower of the Sacred Flame in Gongmen City. After Po and the Five are captured, Mantis was supposedly placed in a cage by Po. When Mantis extinguished the fuse to Shen's cannon and knocked out Boss Wolf, it was then revealed that the "Mantis" inside the cage was really Po's action figure of Mantis, which somehow broke.

> When Po is urged by Ping, to sign for his own personal stuffs being given away to noodle shop customers, he is outraged to find his most treasured `action figures has also been gone`. After he found a rabbit kid practicing kung fu while playing with them, he decided to not claim them. At the same time, the Furious Five came to ask if he has found his treasured figures, Po just says the figures went to the right place, while he has the real Furious Five.

In **Kung fu Panda 3** the Tigress figure was packed by Mr. Ping, along with himself, in Po's package on the trip to Panda Village. After Po arrived, a panda girl called Lei Lei asked Po to give the figure to her. Lei Lei was delighted to see the real Tigress afterwards, and developed a friendship with her.

[image]

For more refer [this](http://kungfupanda.wikia.com/wiki/Furious_Five_action_figures#).